# sessionStorage with and without leading www

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication

I am using browser sessionStorage to store a users login token. However if I login at example.com, I am not logged in at www.example.com. Is there a way to share the session Storage with both example.com and www.example.com? I know with cookies I can set the domain to .example.com. Is there something similar with js? I'm using angularjs if that makes a difference.

Comment: Couldn't you just redirect www to non-www?

Comment: I could do that. I wasn't sure if there was someway to set sessionStorage domain, but a redirect might be easiest